# Can a PS2 Dual Shock work with Call of Duty: Black Ops for PC?

Tags: pc, call-of-duty-black-ops, controllers

Title says it all. I'm a newbie when it comes to this stuff. :)

Answer (score 1):

A PS2 controller requires an adapter in order for it to be attached to a PC.  If the proper drivers and hardware support exist, you may be able to use it as a USB gamepad.  I do not know whether the game supports gamepads, but the answer is probably yes.

Comment: Yes it can, but you need an adapter.

Comment: @MichaelB: I've edited the answer to reflect your comment.

Comment: or probably not..

Answer (score 0):

Most likely not without what DragonLord posted.

You're far better off using a mouse and keyboard. A controller is not even remotely as good as a mouse and keyboard. There isn't a single game or genre that plays better on a controller than on a mouse and keyboard. If you're going to be playing online, using a controller puts you at an enormous disadvantage. When you become proficient with the mouse and keyboard, you will hate controllers.

If you truly want to use a controller and be disadvantaged, invest in a USB gamepad. Do not get a wireless gamepad because there can be very noticeable input delay. A wired Logitech gamepad is your best bet as far as gamepads go. I've noticed that a lot of people use XBOX 360 controllers on their PCs too.

Comment: I would disagree with the sentiment that mouse/keyboard is always better.  I find it much, much easier to navigate the Spy's and Engineer's PDA layouts (in Team Fortress 2) with a 360 controller.  I would also point out 2-D platformers--much easier to handle with a linked D-Pad rather then four separate buttons.

Comment: @Ketura Doesn't make it true. Neither of your statements. Spy and Engineer layouts can be scripted and done infinitely quicker on PC with mouse and keyboard. Platformers also objectively play better on mouse and keyboard. Having four fingers control each of your directions is better than having one finger control each of your directions. This applies to every game and genre, even fighters. A Hadouken on a controller is 236P, whereas a Hadouken on keyboard is 26P. Using WASD that would be S -> D -> Punch. That's fine if you like controllers, but mouse and keyboard is objectively better.

Comment: @Ketura Addendum: You also forget that using a controller merely because you find it easier to navigate a menu SEVERELY gimps your actual combat ability. Navigating menus means nothing when you can't aim due to having an inherent hardware disadvantage. With two players of identical skill playing against each other, one using a controller and the other using a mouse and keyboard, no matter what the game is the player with the mouse and keyboard has an objective advantage and will always win, flukes aside. There's a reason why competitive gaming and speedrunning is done primarily on PC.

Comment: You can't just categorically say whether controller is "better" or keyboard/mouse is "better", because of the word "better".  "more buttons" is objective, "easier to use" is probably subjective and "better" is definitely subjective.